# Redirection between 2 websites using Azure Web Application Gateway

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

is there a way to redirect between 2 websites in Azure Web Application Gateway or any other Azure service?
For example:
I have an external website (not hosted in Azure) but I own the DNS records.
I need to redirect [www.bakery.com/contactus](http://www.bakery.com/contactus) to another website [www.bakeryowner.com/baker](http://www.bakeryowner.com/baker) page.
I also own bakeryowner.com dns records.

Is it possible to redirect between the 2 inside Azure services and this look seamless to end user?

Many Thanks
Amy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Azure Web Application Gateway could meet your need.

Here is the official tutorial: [Create an application gateway with external redirection using Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/redirect-external-site-powershell)

[image]

Comment: Hi Doris, maybe I am not following but I can't see how that doc will help me as I cannot configure any page redir. However I found this  [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/redirect-overview). Would the 301 redirect setting help me?

Comment: or maybe this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/rewrite-url-portal

Comment: I thought this is what you need... Does this part help you? @Maelito

Comment: Hi Doris, I just found out more about this case. 

The old company’s website will disappear but we will keep the domain. 

So all I need is to redirect the domain to a page in the main company’s website page.